# GitHub / private repository / SSH: go get/go mod tidy fail, while git clone is working

Tags: windows, git, go, ssh

I hope to find the answer to the question which is bothering me for the past couple of days - I have read a lot of threads, helpers, and publications, and do not seem to find a solution.
I am a bit new with SSH.

The problem is as follows:
I cannot get/install/refresh the modules belonging to my project, when using `go get` or `go mod tidy` commands,
while `git clone` of the same repo via SSH in any of the terminals or via TortoiseGit are working fine,
i.e. I can clone, but I cannot build.

getting a module fails the following way (personal data obfuscated):

```
    example.com/hello/PROJECTS/src/git.<orgname>.com/<reponame>/<subreponame>/tests/functional/resources tested by
    example.com/hello/PROJECTS/src/git.<orgname>.com/<reponame>/<subreponame>/tests/functional/resources.test imports
    git.<orgname>.com/<reponame>/<subreponame>/tests/functional/resources/vm_specific: module git.<orgname>.com/<reponame>/<subreponame>/tests/functional/resources/vm_specific: git ls-remote -q origin in C:\GO\PROJECTS\pkg\mod\cache\vcs\a5d519aeafc0ac08e2b20d7c8a6a8b2cea11cda88cb058cf2ebcc079d07b260a: exit status 128:
    debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> 'C:\\Users\\<username>/.ssh/known_hosts'
    debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> 'C:\\Users\\<username>/.ssh/known_hosts2'
    debug2: resolving "git.<orgname>.com" port <port>
    debug3: resolve_host: lookup git.<orgname>.com:<port>
    debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
    debug1: Connecting to git.<orgname>.com [10.XXX.X.XX] port <port>.
    debug1: Connection established.
    ...
    debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.9
    debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version APACHE-SSHD-2.4.0
    debug1: compat_banner: no match: APACHE-SSHD-2.4.0
    debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
    debug1: Authenticating to git.<orgname>.com:<port> as 'git'
    ...
    debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
    ...
    debug3: send packet: type 50
    debug3: receive packet: type 52
    Authenticated to git.<orgname>.com ([10.XXX.X.XX]:<port>) using "publickey".
    ...
    debug1: Sending command: git-upload-pack '/scm/<reponame>/<subreponame>.git'
    debug2: channel 0: request exec confirm 1
    debug3: send packet: type 98
    debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback done
    debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 2097152 rmax 32768
    debug3: receive packet: type 99
    debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
    debug2: exec request accepted on channel 0
    debug2: channel 0: rcvd ext data 106
    debug3: receive packet: type 96
    debug2: channel 0: rcvd eof
    debug2: channel 0: output open -> drain
    debug3: receive packet: type 98
    debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
    debug3: receive packet: type 97
    debug2: channel 0: rcvd close
    debug2: chan_shutdown_read: channel 0: (i0 o1 sock -1 wfd 4 efd 6 [write])
    debug2: channel 0: input open -> closed
    debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close
    debug2: channel 0: obuf_empty delayed efd 6/(106)
    debug2: channel 0: written 106 to efd 6
    Repository not found
    The requested repository does not exist, or you do not have permission to access it.
    debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close
    debug2: channel 0: obuf empty
    debug2: chan_shutdown_write: channel 0: (i3 o1 sock -1 wfd 5 efd 6 [write])
    debug2: channel 0: output drain -> closed
    fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

    Please make sure you have the correct access rights
    and the repository exists.
    debug2: channel 0: almost dead
    debug2: channel 0: gc: notify user
    debug2: channel 0: gc: user detached
    debug2: channel 0: send close
    debug3: send packet: type 97
    debug2: channel 0: is dead
    debug2: channel 0: garbage collecting
    debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
    debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
      #0 client-session (t4 r0 i3/0 o3/0 e[write]/0 fd -1/-1/6 sock -1 cc -1 io 0x00/0x08)

    debug3: send packet: type 1
    Transferred: sent 3268, received 2200 bytes, in 0.2 seconds
    Bytes per second: sent 15169.6, received 10212.1
    debug1: Exit status 1
```

If a fuller log is needed I can upload it somewhere.

last rows of `ssh -T(vvv set as default) git@git.<orgname>.com`:

```
    debug3: send packet: type 50
    debug3: receive packet: type 52
    debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
    Authenticated to git.<orgname>.com ([10.XXX.X.XX]:<port>).
    debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
    debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
    debug2: channel 0: send open
    debug3: send packet: type 90
    debug1: Entering interactive session.
    debug1: pledge: filesystem full
    debug3: receive packet: type 91
    debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback start
    debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
    debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IP_TOS 0x08
    debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
    debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
    debug3: send packet: type 98
    debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback done
    debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 2097152 rmax 32768
    debug3: receive packet: type 100
    debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 100 id 0
    shell request failed on channel 0
```

I am using a public key deriving from a key generated by ssh-keygen of OpenSSH - it is freshly generated and is added to my Git profile.
`git clone` is thus working fine which is driving me insane already.
I already have the most part of the modules which fail to be checked in the remote private repo, which is even crazier.

I dislike this part, which most probably means that I have issues with my certificate -

> Authenticated to git..com ([10.XXX.X.XX]:) using
> "publickey".

and this part, as `OpenSSH on AIX requests PKCS12 support by default when EFS is enabled and non-AIX systems may reject these PKCS12 requests.`

> ```
>     debug2: channel 0: obuf_empty delayed efd 6/(106)
>     debug2: channel 0: written 106 to efd 6
> ```

See changes in my config below.

**My environment:**

- Win10 Enterprise
- Git version - 2.31.1.windows.1
- I usually clone via TortoiseGit 2.13.0.1
- SSH client being used within CMD/Powershell - OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.9, installed manually

**go env:** (personal data obfuscated)

```
    set GO111MODULE=
    set GOARCH=amd64
    set GOBIN=
    set GOCACHE=C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\go-build
    set GOENV=C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\go\env
    set GOEXE=.exe
    set GOEXPERIMENT=
    set GOFLAGS=
    set GOHOSTARCH=amd64
    set GOHOSTOS=windows
    set GOINSECURE=
    set GOMODCACHE=C:\Program Files\Go\pkg\mod
    set GONOPROXY=*.<orgname>.com;git.<orgname>.com/users/<username>
    set GONOSUMDB=*.<orgname>.com;git.<orgname>.com/users/<username>
    set GOOS=windows
    set GOPATH=C:\Program Files\Go
    set GOPRIVATE=*.<orgname>.com;git.<orgname>.com/users/<username>
    set GOPROXY=https://proxy.golang.org,direct
    set GOROOT=C:\Program Files\Go
    set GOSUMDB=sum.golang.org
    set GOTMPDIR=
    set GOTOOLDIR=C:\Program Files\Go\pkg\tool\windows_amd64
    set GOVCS=
    set GOVERSION=go1.18.3
    set GCCGO=gccgo
    set GOAMD64=v1
    set AR=ar
    set CC=gcc
    set CXX=g++
    set CGO_ENABLED=1
    set GOMOD=NUL
    set GOWORK=
    set CGO_CFLAGS=-g -O2
    set CGO_CPPFLAGS=
    set CGO_CXXFLAGS=-g -O2
    set CGO_FFLAGS=-g -O2
    set CGO_LDFLAGS=-g -O2
    set PKG_CONFIG=pkg-config
    set GOGCCFLAGS=-m64 -mthreads -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=C:\Users\USER~1.NAM\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build1143995380=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches
```

**My SSH config:**

```
    # GITHUB FOR SRC
        Host git.<orgname>.com
           ServerAliveInterval 600
           TCPKeepAlive yes
           IPQoS throughput
           AddKeysToAgent yes
           HostName git.<orgname>.com
           Port <port>
           User <username>
           PreferredAuthentications publickey
           IdentityFile C:\Users\<username>\.ssh\git_rsa
           #IdentityFile ~/.ssh/git_rsa
           PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes +ssh-rsa
           #ForwardAgent no
           #AllowPKCS12KeystoreAutoOpen no
           LogLevel DEBUG3
```

- The certificate was previously added to the agent, but I have specified it here to be sure, and the correct certificate seems to be taken for authentication according to the log.
- It does not have a passphrase.
- I do not have totally unknown entries in my `known-hosts`, and the correct entry judging by a certificate timestamp is being used.
- I found that the PKCS12 requests can be disabled by `AllowPKCS12KeystoreAutoOpen` set to `no`, but it is being marked as a bad option -

  ```
   C:\GO\PROJECTS\src\git.<orgname>.com\<reponame>\<subreponame>>go get git.<orgname>.com/<name>/go-service/log
   go: module git.<orgname>.com/<name>/go-service/log: git ls-remote -q origin in C:\GO\PROJECTS\pkg\mod\cache\vcs\d0d607237eeba0d1c9d5ce996ed36c0f3746b2c8f94b538ace2d3f2a9476839e: exit status 128:
       C:\\Users\\<username>/.ssh/config: line 15: Bad configuration option: allowpkcs12keystoreautoopen
       C:\\Users\\<username>/.ssh/config: terminating, 1 bad configuration options
  ```

**GIT configs:**

- global:

  ```
   [user]
       name = <username>
       email = <usrname>@<orgname>.com

   [url "ssh://git@git.<orgname>.com:<port>/"]
       insteadOf = https://git.<orgname>.com
  ```
- system:

  ```
   [url "ssh://git@git.<orgname>.com:<port>/"]
       insteadOf = https://git.<orgname>.com/
  ```

**git remote -v:**

```
    origin  ssh://git@git.<orgname>.com:<port>/~<username>/<subreponame>.git (fetch)
    origin  ssh://git@git.<orgname>.com:<port>/~<username>/<subreponame>.git (push)
```

- the same I use for cloning,

**repo config:**

```
    [remote "origin"]
        url = ssh://git@git.<orgname>.com:<port>/~<username>/<subreponame>.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

I tried both ssh:// and git@git... and it did not help.

**module config** (set automatically), however:

```
    [remote "origin"]
        url = https://git.<orgname>.com/scm/<reponame>/<subreponame>.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

I am out of ideas at this moment.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend not to use `go get` with private repositories. This command caches repositories at pkg.go.dev and thus exposes them to the world. I was so embarrassed to find our private development published openly there.

I deploy my private dependencies in the file system manually and specify the dependency in `go.mod` using replace:

```
require your.server/your/package 1.2.3

replace your.server/your/package 1.2.3 => /path/to/local/your/package
```

Comment: 'go get' was mostly for test purposes, but thank you for sharing.
will try to replace the dependencies manually.

Answer (score 0):

That was an issue with repository - it was not really made to work with dependencies, and was not meant to work with modules and module-related requests. C'est la vie, but at least I've learned a lot about SSH and GIT interaction.